# how to replace the wordpress navigation menu with another navigation menu?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, menu, filter, navigation

im working on a navigation menu plugin 
, and i want to replace the default menu with my menu automatically 
there's a filter , function , something in wordpress i messing ?
thanks advanced , and sorry for my English

Answer (score 0):

try wordpress Mega Menu plugin [See The Demo](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jquery-mega-menu/)

Answer (score 0):

In wordpress you can set your navigation menu through this function `wp_nav_menu( $args );`

For detailed listing follow the link - [Link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu)

You need to set value for the `menu` parameter.

Let me know if this is what you are asking about or something else.